# How to manage application.conf in several environments with play 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

With Play 1.2, I can prefix the configuration keys with the framework ID or application mode as follows:

```
# Production configuration
%prod.http.port=80
%prod.application.log=INFO
%prod.application.mode=prod
```

But it doesn't seem to work with 2.0.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: [here is the SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35324046/492918) to a solution using Play2.4.6 Java

Answer (score 43):

Play 2 doesn't force you to use any particular method to manage your environments. But it provides you with powerful and flexible tools to implement it yourself according to the needs of your project.

For instance a common pattern is keeping common environment settings in one file and having environment-specific overrides in other files. In order to do that you will need a [custom Global object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaGlobal) (you can put it right into the `./app/Global.scala`). The following code is valid as of Play 2.1.1 (Scala 2.10):

```scala
import java.io.File
import play.api._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {
    val modeSpecificConfig = config ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(s"application.${mode.toString.toLowerCase}.conf"))
    super.onLoadConfig(modeSpecificConfig, path, classloader, mode)
  }
}
```

Now you can put `application.dev.conf`, `application.test.conf`, and `application.prod.conf` into your `./conf` with environment specific overrides (while keeping common settings in `application.conf`).

In this sample we're relying on the Play's own `mode` which usually makes sense, but you can be as granular as you want and use environment variables or whatever you feel like.

See also: [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me. When I use this code, anything that is not set in the mode override file seems to get set to Play defaults and not what is in application.conf. I am using `play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_45)`. Can anyone else confirm this behavior? I think it has to do with `ConfigFactory.load`.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for ConfigFactory, I see this for ConfigFactory.load(String): `Loads an application's configuration from the given classpath resource or classpath resource basename, sandwiches it between default reference config and default overrides, and then resolves it.`

Comment: When I switched to ConfigFactory.parseFile, it started working as expected. Don't know if that is the best solution. There might be options you can give to ConfigFactory.load so that it doesn't merge your overrides with the defaults.

Comment: @mushroom As I mentioned in my answer that simple example was written against Play 2.1.1. My intention was just to illustrate the approach. If you're looking for a copy/paste-ready solution then you'd probably have to tinker on your own a little bit and address your project-specific needs.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did.  Please read my other comments.  I said how I got it to work with my version.

Comment: @coffeesnake This method works for me for Play run/start/test but not dist. Anyone seen this?

Comment: This won't prevent me from passing in the config command line arg will it?  -Dconfig.file=....

Comment: This seems to be deprecated now, according to docs: "This method does not do anything. Instead, specify configuration in your config file or make your own ApplicationLoader (see GuiceApplicationBuilder.loadConfig)"

Comment: [here is the SO link][1] to a solution using Play2.4.6 Java 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35324046/492918

Answer (score 13):

I have had this question for a long time as well and below is the best approach I've learned so far, I got a hint when asking a similar question on the Play 2 google group.

In you application.config use the following syntax to override a configuration value when a system parameter is present:

```
# Local machine fallback URI
mongodb.uri="mongodb://192.168.56.101:27017/application"
# Env variable override
mongodb.uri=${?MONGOLAB_URI}
```

The question mark means that you don't override with the env variable if it is not set. If you just use ${MONGOLAB_URI} you expect the variable to be set and, I assume, you get an exception of some kind if it is not set.

For completeness, here is an example of how you'd read the value:

```
lazy val mongoUri = current.configuration.getString("mongodb.uri").getOrElse("mongodb:///")
```

With this approach there is one caveat: make sure you keep your system param configuration in a SCM of some kind.

Comment: Hi Magnus - how would I create a new env var in the `application.conf` that equals `mongodb.uri` but with `/a.xml` added to it?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: I know this is a *very* old comment but.. you can use something like `my_new_cfg = ${mongodb.uri}"/a.xml"`. This is, of course, assuming you are using the HOCON format for typesafe config.

Answer (score 6):

You have to define a different configuration file with the appropriate properties

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Configuration

There is also a inclusion mechanism that helps you define default values in application.conf and overrides only what is needed for production

Comment: I tried to do this, the only problem im facing is that when I have `db.default.driver, db.default.url, db.default.user, etc` in both the `application.conf` and `prod.conf`, some reason with prod.conf it never connects. But when I REMOVE the db settings from the application.conf and run prod.conf, it works. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: btw, i'm having `prod.conf` including `application.conf`

Comment: Yeah, it seems like Play 2 doesn't let you override default database parameters.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be indepentent from restrited scala run modes you can use JVM properties.
Put modified @coffesnake example to ./app/Global.scala :

```scala
import java.io.File

import play.api._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {
    val environment = System.getProperty("environment")
    val environmentSpecificConfig = config ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(s"application.${environment}.conf"))
    super.onLoadConfig(environmentSpecificConfig, path, classloader, mode)
  }
}
```

Next run play `play`

and start app with environment param `run -Denvironment=prod-server1`

Don't join both command, it doesn't work then

Global configuration will be overrided with environment specific properties from file:

```
./conf/application.prod-server1.conf
```

EDIT:

From time perspective I saw this workaround is unnecessary. It is better to use Play build-in config loading mechanism 
`-Dconfig.file=/etc/play-application/foo-production.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this solution:

in `application.conf` I've defined the default configurations,
in `myUsername.conf` I've included the default configuration and overridden the user specific configuration:

```
include "application.conf"
logger.application=DEBUG
```

then in `Global.java` I've loaded the user specific configuration (if exists):

```
public Configuration onLoadConfig(Configuration config, File path,
        ClassLoader classloader) {

    String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
    File confFile = new File(new File(path, "conf"), username + ".conf");

    if (confFile.exists()) {
        Logger.info("configuration file {} found", confFile.getName());
        return new Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(confFile.getName()));
    } else {
        Logger.info(
                "configuration file {} not found, using default application.conf",
                confFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We just have multiple application.conf files, the default is used during development and we have a prod-applicaton.conf that we simply copy into place when we deploy.

Comment: this works fine but it requires a team to keep both of those files in sync with each other