# Play 2.0 Scala Heroku instance isn't seeing every variable in the Procfile

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, cedar

I'm using Play! 2.0 Scala edition on Heroku. Heroku does not seem to see/use all my configuration variables in the Procfile.

For instance, in my application.conf I have the following variables (amongst others):

```
mongodb.default.db = "nyancat"
mongodb.default.host = "localhost"
mongodb.default.port = 27017
```

These should be the defaults for local development. However, I want my Heroku instance to use a MongoLabs instance. (Unfortunately, Salat doesn't configure with a URI, so I had to break it down into host, port, yada yada, i.e. MONGOLAB_URI isn't used)

My Procfile now looks like this:

```
☆  cat Procfile                                             
web: target/start -Dsecurehostname="https://example.org" \
-Dhostname="http://example.org" -Dhttp.port=$PORT \
-DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver \
-Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL -Dredis=$REDISTOGO_URL \
-Dmailgun.apikey=$MAILGUN_API_KEY -Dmongodb.default.db="heroku_appXXXXXXX" \
-Dmongodb.default.host="dsXXXXXX.mongolab.com" -Dmongodb.default.port=XXXXX \
-Dmongodb.default.user="heroku_appXXXXXXX" \
-Dmongodb.default.password="foobared_not"
```

I push and restart, but the remote MongoDB connection still says it connects on localhost:27017

Redis and everything else works fine and dandy.

The remote log shows this when starting up, and it clearly doesn't contain all the parameters in my Procfile:

```
2012-05-20T19:35:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command \
`target/start -Dhostname="https://example.org" -Dhttp.port=XXXXX \
-DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver \
-Ddb.default.url=<HIDDEN> -Dredis=<HIDDEN> -Dmailgun.apikey=<HIDDEN>`
```

I.e. no `mongo.*` parameters anywhere in the logs.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything, thanks fellas.

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to emulate Heroku locally, using `sbt stage` and running the app with `foreman start`. I set the environment variables which *would* be set by Heroku, and run it like this:

```
app git:(master) ☆  DATABASE_URL="jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase;MODE=PostgreSQL" \
  REDISTOGO_URL="redis://ignored:foobared@localhost:6379/" \
  foreman start
20:20:27 web.1     | started with pid 43382
20:20:27 web.1     | Play server process ID is 43382
20:20:29 web.1     | [info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase
20:20:29 web.1     | [info] play - mongodb [default] connected at "heroku_appXXXXXXX"@"dsXXXXXX.mongolab.com":XXXXX/"heroku_appXXXXXXX"
20:20:30 web.1     | [info] play - Application started (Prod)
20:20:30 web.1     | [info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 5000...
```

foreman picks up my PRODUCTION MongoDB values as it is in the Procfile, which validates my argument that Heroku is perhaps using an older version of my Procfile for some unknown reason.

On my Heroku instance, the Procfile is definitely does not have the immutable flag set either:

```
~ $ lsattr Procfile
------------------- Procfile
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I'm using [MongoDB Salat plugin for Play Framework 2 (Scala only)](https://github.com/leon/play-salat).

Here's a pattern I picked up:

Every push **succeeded** before I started implementing MongoDB support.

Then I integrated the [Salat plugin](https://github.com/leon/play-salat), signed up for a MongoLabs account, and the fun started. The plugin above doesn't support [com.mongodb.MongoURI](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.2/com/mongodb/MongoURI.html) and due to the way it parses configuration, it will blow up if you give it `-Dmongodb.uri`. It expects a keyspace, like "default".

Which brings us back to the `mongodb.default.*` switches I've been using above.

Now my development cycle looks like this:

```
push, fail
push (without changes), success, but seemingly with old Procfile
<make change>
push, fail
push (without changes), success, but seemingly with old Procfile
<make change>
push, fail
push (without changes), success, but seemingly with old Procfile
...
```

And most annoyingly, the failing push just logs this:

```
Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
```

...and the `heroku logs -t` output only show this:

```
2012-05-22T07:23:59+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: unrecognized error
```

It works locally, BTW.

I've brought all this so Heroku support's attention since it could be that they swallow errors thrown by [Typesafe's Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) when it could just make things clearer from the start.

I've also asked them not to allow those second pushes to succeed, but then use an old Procfile. Very misleading.

Needless to say, I'm now also implementing MongoURI support for the Salat plugin.

---

**UPDATE 3**

[I've implemented support](https://github.com/leon/play-salat/pull/8) for `mongodb.default.uri` in the Play! Salat plugin (and deployed it using lib/), but Heroku still throws an error whenever I push anything mongo-related in my Procfile.

I've asked Heroku support the same question, and perhaps someone here can answer: does Heroku limit the variables you can use in Procfile?

Comment: I have a working example of Play 2 + MongoDB here: https://github.com/jamesward/play2bars/tree/scala-mongodb  Maybe that will help figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Thanks James, I'll give it a shot. Otherwise I'll see you on Thursday night at LFPUG :)

Comment: @JamesWard the ```-Dmongodb.uri=$MONGOHQ_URL``` bit: is there any significance to the naming of JVM switches? I.e. does Heroku only accept a pre-set list of variable names? The ones I used were called ```mongodb.default.*```. I'm starting to think an older version of my Procfile is cached/being used.

Comment: Setting those Java system settings just overrides the settings in the Play config file.  It's an easy way to change Play settings in a different environment.  I don't think there is any way that the settings are being cached.  Have you committed the change into your git repo and pushed?

Comment: Also you might want to submit a support request.  Another option would be to have a `conf/prod.conf` file that has those settings and then use it with a Procfile containing: `web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dconfig.file=conf/prod.conf` where the `prod.conf` contains something like:
https://github.com/jamesward/zentasks/blob/master/conf/prod.conf

Comment: Some variables trip up the stack, see my answer. Thanks James!

Comment: Not my answer, I meant **UPDATE 2**. I'll see what Heroku support says, and if my Salat plugin pull request is accepted, I'll answer here.

Comment: My only guess is that it is the length of the command in the `Procfile` that might be limited.  Did you try the prod config file approach?

Comment: This turned out to be the case, thanks James.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the Procfile's start command can be a **maximum of 255 characters long**. I expect all your mongodb configurations are way beyond that.

I suggest you refer to an [alternative configuration file](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ProductionConfiguration). for your non [environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) dependant configurations E.g.:

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT -Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL \
-Dredis=$REDISTOGO_URL -Dmailgun.apikey=$MAILGUN_API_KEY \
-Dconfig.resource=heroku-prod.conf
```

And in conf/heroku-prod.conf:

```
include "application.conf"                                        

securehostname="https://example.org" 
hostname="http://example.org" 
applyEvolutions.default=true
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
mongodb.default.db="heroku_appXXXXXXX"
mongodb.default.host="dsXXXXXX.mongolab.com"
mongodb.default.port=XXXXX \
mongodb.default.user="heroku_appXXXXXXX"
mongodb.default.password="foobared_not"
```

Comment: This could very well be it--where is it documented? (I'll do another Git bisect later)

Comment: Don't know where it is documented but I came across a similar issue and through support/assist from Heroku they mentioned the 255 char restriction. And modifying my Procfile fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that some variables are enabled by plugins? 
I didn't checked the heroku api, but it could be a clue.

The second point is how you accessed those variables, my guess is that the typesafe configuration system doesn't fallback to command line options.

The last point is according to https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala you can add an application.conf in the root of the classpath , it will be used in production mode instead of explicitly retrieving it from conf/.

My 2c

Comment: It could be that certain variables are enabled by Heroku add-ons (not Play plugins). I've asked Heroku support about this (waiting for an answer), because it's not clear from the documentation. Play accepts -D switches on top of application.conf, which is how Heroku should init my app.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear while talking about plugins... actually I was talking about heroku add-ons. So that, only those variables that are declared by add-ons are allowed (just guessing). For play 2.0 and env variables, there is an aswer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723224/how-to-manage-application-conf-in-several-environments-with-play-2-0 that says how to do with fall back. For the -D options, what could be tried is to used the -Dconfig.file *only* (or config.resource, url) pointing the PROD set?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try doing your configuration like this in application.conf ....

I'm not sure if this heroku, production mode, or something else but I have noticed something strange about environment variables set with 'heroku config' also.

In application.conf, if one uses the notation

```
google.client=$(GOOGCLIENTID)
```

everything seems ok running on the local workstation.  I can verify with 'heroku config' that the variable is set, but it clearly is not propagated to the configuration when running on heroku.

However, this notation works ok:

```
google.client=$(?GOOGCLIENTID)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried ```-Dconfig.resource``` from the [Heroku Production Configuration](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ProductionConfiguration) docs, and added it to the beginning of my Procfile. The log still just says ```2012-05-21T12:36:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/start -Dhostname="https:...``` i.e. it doesn't pick up the new switch. I think an old version of my Procfile is cached. Still waiting for Heroku support to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any funny characters in $MAILGUN_API_KEY? Try moving -Dmailgun.apikey=$MAILGUN_API_KEY to the end...

Comment: ```-Dsecurehostname="https://example.org"``` is omitted and it's the first parameter. I also later on tried a new parameter altogether (towards the start of the Procfile) and it had no effect.

Comment: I also validated my Procfile with ```foreman check```, and it logs ```valid procfile detected (web)```.