# Playframework 2 - Storing your credentials

Tags: configuration, playframework-2.0, credentials

Where do you store you credentials like secret key , mail passwords, db passwords?

I made a post on https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19785/security-concerns-about-my-webapp/19786#19786

And it seems the best way to store the credentials is on an external server.

But play2 uses the application.conf to do this.

- So how and where do you store your credentials in play2?

**Update 1:**

Okay I am using heroku.

I set my enviroment variable like this:

```
heroku config:add test=ITWORKS
```

in application.conf I added

```
sometest=${test}
```

I trying to access it like this:

```
Logger.info(Play.application().configuration().getString("sometest"));
```

But I get the following error:

```
UnresolvedSubstitution: conf\application.conf: 54: Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${test}
```

So I guess play2 doesn't find the variable test because it is on heroku. But then I also added it in my local windows environment -> still the same error.

Any idea what is wrong?

**Update2:**

Okay it works, I just have to reboot after I added an env variable.

Last question:

It's kinda annoying to add the system variable everytime on my local machine. Is there a dev mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ad. 3:** In Play `application.conf` is not accesible via any `route` or other kind of `path` so it can not be considered as 'placed in webroot'. Terry's advice is proper in PHP, but doesn't fit to Play (he warned, that he don't know the framework of course). He gives a sample of PHP script, but believe me, the diffrence between access to `http://somdomain.tld/config.php` and Play's `conf/application.conf` is huge. They can't be compared directly.

Storing credentials in `application.conf` is the safest (and fastest) way for now, I can't imagine a way to decompile the file in browser even if parser would die (which isn't possible as it's not PHP). If you'll decide to store credentials in some distant location, you'll gain the  new risk, as you will need to additionally check if client has permissions to get the config, time required for application's start will rise etc, etc.

**Update 1:**

Using environment variables is not a secure way - as Marius pointed, it will appear in the process list, so you will show your credentials to each admin and I'm pretty sure that you don't want do that with ie. your email.

In Heroku of course it's a way for passing **their** DB connection URL, but other credentials should be stored in config file. Finally remember that [Procfile command length is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10746180/1066240) to 255 chars, so placing all credential in it will cause, that your app won't start some day.

Resolution in this case is using [alernative configuration files](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ProductionConfiguration), scenario is quite simple

1. in your `application.conf` keep an URL to your production database If it's Heroku most probably `db.default.user` and `db.default.password` should be commented as common heroku URL contains credentials in it.
2. For your local version create a file ie: `conf/local_postgres.conf` include application.conf at the beginning and override/add all required configuration keys like credentials to your local Postgres DB. Additionally you can set there other things, change logging levels, enable `smtp.mock`, etc.
3. Run your app locally with this conf. (note, I had some problem with `-Dconfig.resource` so I had to use `-Dconfig.file` syntax instead, you have to find which method will be working good in your system) ie.

   ```
   play -Dconfig.resource=local_postgres.conf "~run 9123"
   ```

   Tip: Using non default port is the easiest way to "demonstrate" that you're working with local config. If you'll forget that you have alternative config and will start your app with common `play ~run` command, your app in location `http://localhost:9123` will be just unavailable.
4. Create a bash script `run-local` (or `run-local.bat` file in Windows) and place there command from previous point. Ignore it in `.gitignore` file.

From now you'll be running the application for local development with the script from point 4.  While pushing to Heroku it will deploy your app with values from `application.conf` as you don't set alternative config in the Procfile. What's more with some other combinations you can run locally your application with Heroku's SQL to perform evolutions without pushing it to deployment, or check newest fix-pack. Of course you have to always make sure that you're developing on the local version of database, otherwise there's a risk that you accidentally change/destroy your life data.

**Update 2:**

Finally using `*.conf` files is better than storing it in separate classes in case when you have to change configuration for different locations (as mentioned yet, team working on the same code, dev/prod environments etc.)

Of course can be shortened to:

```java
import play.Configuration;
import play.Play;

// ...
Configuration cfg = Play.application().configuration();

cfg.getString("smtp.password");
cfg.getBoolean("smtp.mock");
cfg.getInt("smtp.port");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one question, Marius recommended me to use Environment variables, but it would be kinda annoying to add them on my local machine because otherwise it would obviously not work. The worst part is that I need to reboot my computer every time i add a new variable. So is there a workaround for my local machine?

Comment: I'd do it the other way round - use application.conf locally and then include it with `include "application.conf"` in your `prod.conf`, so you don't have to remember running play with an extra config file.

Comment: And passing parameters on the command line is not recommended, but setting them via `heroku config:add` is the preferred way.

Comment: @MariusSoutier: It's matter of taste, while 'solo' development most probably your (reversed to mine) approach will be ok, but when working in the team we found, it's still required to use individual configs per team mate , so we decided that `application.conf` will keep credentials for production. Of course if you working with new or 'untrasted' developers it's best do not include sensitive credentials in the shared repositories and push `prod.conf` only to Heroku (or keep in in the file outside the git and include with `-Dconfig.file=/home/user/prod.conf` if possible)

Comment: So to be absolutely clear, It is completely safe to put my sensitive data in the `application.conf` (cleartext)? Would it make a difference if put the senstive data in `application.conf` or in a seperate java class? something like `public static int password = 12345`

Comment: @MaikKlein: Yes it's absolutely safest. Until you won't create some methods to display credentials in your template. Placing it in separate java class doesn't make a sense.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! It just would be easier to write. `Play.application().configuration().getString("password")` vs `Config.password` and I wouldn't have to worry about a typo.

Answer (score 4):

`application.conf` supports environment variables, e.g. `db.default.user=${DB_USER}`. You can pass it as a console parameter (which is not safe since it appears in `ps`), or more safely set it as an environment variable.

On Heroku, set the environment variable via `heroku config`, e.g. `heroku config:add DB_USER=MyDBAdmin`.

Locally you can set them via `export DB_USER=MyDBAdmin`, or add them to your `~/.bash_profile` (if you use bash).

Comment: I tried to use it but I encountered an error -> updated my first post