# environmental variable substitution when including another configuration file in Play 2.2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

Is it possible to use environmental variable substitution when including another configuration file?

I would like to have something like that:

```
include "${HOME}/.foo/credentials.conf"
```

[Configuration documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Configuration) mentions *locating resources* and *include substitution* but not together.

This works:

```
include "/home/me/.foo/credentials.conf"
```

and my HOME is correctly set.

But all attempts to make `include "${HOME}/.foo/credentials.conf"` so far failed

Background:

I deliberately want to keep credentials and other sensitive data out of our code base but have them available for local dev environments for testing. I am aware of more sophisticated solutions using external storage like hinted here [Playframework 2 - Storing your credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284312/playframework-2-storing-your-credentials) and we use something similar for live and preview environments but these are not suitable for local dev setup.

An alternative is to include credentials file to code base after all but use git ignore to prevent pushing it, but it is fragile solution and risk is someone will eventually push it and compromise credentials.

Answer (score 1):

TBH I'm not even able to include file with absolute path `/home/me...` anyway approach which will work for you is just using alternative conf file as described in [the same doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Configuration):

In file **/home/me/.foo/credentials.conf** you need to include `application.conf` - Play will fallback it to the file in classpath (this which is under VCS):

```
include "application.conf"
myCredentials.user="Espinosa"
myCredentials.password="fooBar123"
```

then `run`/`start` your app with this config file locally:

```
play -Dconfig.file=${HOME}/.foo/credentials.conf ~run
```

and that's it.

Note: of course it's easier to setup this addition in your IDE (i.e. IntelliJ: *Run* > *Edit configurations*) or write a shell script containing this command

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this solution, sorry not to mentioning it. There is several issues with this approach - 1) I want the flexibility of potentially several included files, not only credentials. Your approach would require complicated chaining or merging.  2) more fiddly launch as per your answer. I still thing that gitignore way is more practical, unless the credential are somewhat ultra sensitive. My question was really about if/how you can use substitution variables in include parameter.