# How to customize application.conf per environment with Play 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to setup different application.conf files per environment (test, staging, prod, etc.).

The documentation [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Configuration) indicates it can be done by passing a parameter -Dconfig.resource= such as:

> play -Dconfig.resource=application.test.conf run

However, this does not seem to work for me - no matter what value I input, I still get my default configuration (application.conf). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15937831/247546 for arguably cleaner alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Two potential workarounds to the issue encountered with config.resource:
1) One can override a specific property using the -D command-line option, such as this:

> play -Ddb.default.url="mysql://myuser:mypassword@localhost/dev" run

2) Overriding the configuration file works if you use the config.file property:

> play -Dconfig.file=/conf/application.test.conf run

This requires entering the full path to the config file, but at least it works.

Comment: and according to
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ProductionConfiguration
you can, in your new configuration file, include the application.conf in the project :

include "application.conf"

key.to.override=blah