# Play Framework 2.3.8 Java - Overriding default configuration load with mode specific

Tags: java, playframework

I want to implement a mode specific configuration load in Play Framework 2.3.8 using Java. I know that this is achievable in Scala:

```
import java.io.File
import play.api._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {
    val modeSpecificConfig = config ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(s"application.${mode.toString.toLowerCase}.conf"))
    super.onLoadConfig(modeSpecificConfig, path, classloader, mode)
  }
}
```

Currently I managed to implement the same in java but I cannot cast the typesafe-s `ConfigFactory.load(modeSpecificConfigFile)` return object from `com.typesafe.config.Config` to `play.Configuration`:

```
 @Override
    public Configuration onLoadConfig(Configuration configuration, File file, ClassLoader classLoader, Mode mode) {
        String modeSpecificConfigFile = "application." + mode.toString().toLowerCase() + ".conf";
        Logger.debug("Loading mode specific configuration from: " + modeSpecificConfigFile);
        Configuration modeSpecificConfig = ConfigFactory.load(modeSpecificConfigFile);
        return super.onLoadConfig(modeSpecificConfig , file, classLoader);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it into `play.Configuration`:

```
Configuration modeSpecificConfig = new play.Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(modeSpecificConfigFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution **doesn't work** in **Play 2.4.6**, because as it says [in docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/GlobalSettings.html#onLoadConfig-play.Configuration-java.io.File-java.lang.ClassLoader-) :
*onLoadConfig Deprecated. This method does not do anything. Instead, specify configuration in your config file or make your own ApplicationLoader (see GuiceApplicationBuilder.loadConfig).*

Thus I've implemented a *simpler alternative solution*, a custom Configuration loader, sharing sample code below.

First, assuming you already have all your parameters in "application.conf"
then create "application.prod.conf" for PROD environment
and (optionally) create "application.dev.conf" for DEV environment

Sample **application.prod.conf**

```
# include the main config file, aka make all common params usable  
include "application.conf"  

# PROD specific params, you can also override params from the included conf  
param.for.prod.1 = "etc etc"  
here.override.for.prod = "blabla"
```

usable across your app : **ConfigManager.java**

```
public class ConfigManager {
    public static play.Configuration modeSpecificConfig = new play.Configuration(
        ConfigFactory.load(
            "application." + Play.mode().toString().toLowerCase() + ".conf"
            )
        );
}
```

Now environment specific params are accessible across your app, you can get any param by using ConfigManager, for example:

```
ConfigManager.modeSpecificConfig.getString("keyname");  
ConfigManager.modeSpecificConfig.getInt("keyname2");
```